# What is the right way of building a long scroll list of button widgets in Motif?

Tags: linux, solaris, x11, motif

I'm dealing with an old Motif application that needs to load and display a long list of entries (around 1500). It creates and manages an instance of `xmFormWidgetClass` via `XtVaCreateManagedWidget()` and then it stuffs it with a bunch of linear hierarchies `xmFrameWidgetClass->xmFormWidgetClass->xmFormWidgetClass->xmPushButtonWidgetClass`. Each `PushButton` contains a multi-line label. When this this thing is being populated, it takes a lot of CPU, which it spends doing some geometry calculations inside of X/Motif libraries. The pace at which new buttons are added, degrades very quickly. It looks like there is an O(N) algorithm being used inside of `XtVaCreateManagedWidget()`.

The things get much much better if I do `XtUnrealizeWidget()` on the original instance of the `xmFormWidgetClass`. Entries are being added at almost constant speed but then I cannot find a way to display the whole thing that I built. `XtRealizeWidget()` for the original instance of the `xmFormWidgetClass` does not render it in the window.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to populate the hierarchy and then calculate the geometry and render it to the screen at once?

Redesigning the application is an option but it is a last resort type on an option.

Any advice that keeps me within Motif libraries will be highly appreciated!

Regards,
/Sergey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `XtManageChild` after `XtRealizeWidget`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, when I do that on the parent widget, which I unrealize before, it still does not render on the screen...

Answer (score 1):

Try creating all widgets unmanaged and place them on a WidgetList, then call XtManageChildren(). Please see the following reference

http://www.s-and-b.su/syshlp/motif_guide/MotifProgGuide/Making_Widgets_Visible.html

Every time an individual widget is managed the parent changed_managed procedure is called.
XtManageChildren calls the changed_manage procedure only once.  This may help.